# Transform \textquotedbl quotes to curly quotes

Tags: text-manipulation, quotation

**Background**

I use pdfLaTeX and I have applied `\textquotedbl` throughout a long text and I am wondering if there is an efficient way to transform all straight quotes to curly ones by modifying `\textquotedbl`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE)**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[OT6,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\noindent \textquotedbl Lorem ipsum\textquotedbl

\end{document}
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Desired output**

[image]

Comment: do you really have a space before the `\textquotedouble` on the right? (that makes it harder) and do you really want 99 (closing) quotes for both the left and right quotes (that looks very odd by English conventions at least)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed the space before \textquotedbl and the reason why I wish to request 99 closing quotes it's because of the Swedish standard. In English it's 69.

Comment: well just `\renewcommand\textquotedouble{''}` should work I think.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Excellent solution, it should be `\renewcommand\textquotedbl{''}`

Comment: er yes:-)......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could globally change all the `\textquotedbl` to `\textquotedblright` in your text editor (this might be best if the text may need to be merged with other documents) or simply redefine `\textquotedbl` to make 99 quotes with

```
\renewcommand\textquotedbl{''}
```

or

```
\renewcommand\textquotedbl{\textquotedblright}
```